# Restrict IAM User access to particular S3 Bucket directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm setting up IAM User only access to the particular bucket folder objects to downloads and restricts to other buckets and sub-folders

```
{
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement":[
      {
         "Sid":"AllowListBucketIfSpecificPrefixIsIncludedInRequest",
         "Action":["s3:ListBucket"],
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"],
         "Condition":{
            "StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["downloads/*"]
            }
         }
      },
      {
        "Sid":"AllowUserToReadWriteObjectDataInDownloadsFolder", 
        "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
        "Effect":"Allow",
        "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/downloads/*"]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: And there’s some part of this you don’t know how to do? Because you don’t know the syntax? Or because the syntax you have doesn’t work? (What does happen? What’s going wrong?)

Comment: @Rup - Getting an error "Listing Directory Failed" Did I miss anything on the above policy snippet?